# How to invert video with v4l2loopback and gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer, v4l2loopback

I am trying to vertically invert video but I get the following:

`GST_DEBUG=2 gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert ! videoflip method=vertical-flip ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video1
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
0:00:00.404780204 32410      0x23b1e30 WARN                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:2206:gst_v4l2_object_probe_caps_for_format_and_size:<v4l2sink0> Unknown frame interval type at YUYV@48x32: 0
New clock: GstSystemClock
0:00:00.404881855 32410      0x23b1e30 WARN                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:2206:gst_v4l2_object_probe_caps_for_format_and_size:<v4l2sink0> Unknown frame interval type at YUYV@48x32: 0
0:00:00.404943395 32410      0x23b1e30 WARN                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:2206:gst_v4l2_object_probe_caps_for_format_and_size:<v4l2sink0> Unknown frame interval type at UYVY@48x32: 0
0:00:00.405010945 32410      0x23b1e30 WARN                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:2206:gst_v4l2_object_probe_caps_for_format_and_size:<v4l2sink0> Unknown frame interval type at YU12@48x32: 0
0:00:00.405068424 32410      0x23b1e30 WARN                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:2206:gst_v4l2_object_probe_caps_for_format_and_size:<v4l2sink0> Unknown frame interval type at YV12@48x32: 0
0:00:00.405123299 32410      0x23b1e30 WARN                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:2206:gst_v4l2_object_probe_caps_for_format_and_size:<v4l2sink0> Unknown frame interval type at YVU9@48x32: 0
0:00:00.405179552 32410      0x23b1e30 WARN                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:2206:gst_v4l2_object_probe_caps_for_format_and_size:<v4l2sink0> Unknown frame interval type at YUV9@48x32: 0
0:00:00.405234361 32410      0x23b1e30 WARN                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:2206:gst_v4l2_object_probe_caps_for_format_and_size:<v4l2sink0> Unknown frame interval type at RGB4@48x32: 0
0:00:00.405287186 32410      0x23b1e30 WARN                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:2206:gst_v4l2_object_probe_caps_for_format_and_size:<v4l2sink0> Unknown frame interval type at BGR4@48x32: 0
0:00:00.405339302 32410      0x23b1e30 WARN                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:2206:gst_v4l2_object_probe_caps_for_format_and_size:<v4l2sink0> Unknown frame interval type at RGB3@48x32: 0
0:00:00.405396859 32410      0x23b1e30 WARN                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:2206:gst_v4l2_object_probe_caps_for_format_and_size:<v4l2sink0> Unknown frame interval type at BGR3@48x32: 0
0:00:00.405447885 32410      0x23b1e30 WARN                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:2206:gst_v4l2_object_probe_caps_for_format_and_size:<v4l2sink0> Unknown frame interval type at GREY@48x32: 0
0:00:00.405497954 32410      0x23b1e30 WARN                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:2206:gst_v4l2_object_probe_caps_for_format_and_size:<v4l2sink0> Unknown frame interval type at YVYU@48x32: 0
0:00:00.595326610 32410      0x23b1e30 WARN          v4l2bufferpool gstv4l2bufferpool.c:541:gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_set_config:<v4l2src0:pool:src> libv4l2 converter detected, disabling CREATE_BUFS
0:00:00.821482196 32410      0x23b1e30 ERROR          v4l2allocator gstv4l2allocator.c:1299:gst_v4l2_allocator_dqbuf:<v4l2sink0:pool:sink:allocator> buffer 1 was not queued, this indicate a driver bug.
0:00:00.821571739 32410      0x23b1e30 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2943:gst_base_src_loop:<v4l2src0> error: Internal data flow error.
0:00:00.821609647 32410      0x23b1e30 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2943:gst_base_src_loop:<v4l2src0> error: streaming task paused, reason error (-5)
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Internal data flow error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(2943): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
streaming task paused, reason error (-5)
Execution ended after 0:00:00.417011242
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...`

This works if I do not include the videoflip filter. I have tried it with a lot of different caps.
I think I need a more recent version of the v4l2loopback driver, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

It caused by v4l2loopback driver bug
and fixed in 0.10
ref：https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/issues/116